# Is ZFS (filesystem) good for SDcards?

Tags: filesystems, zfs, micro-sd-card

Ive reviewed all filesystems listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

I like ZFS the most out of all of filesystems listed there. **But is it the best choice for microSDCards?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it doesn't really matter which filesystem you use. In practice there are some things to reconsider:

- You can only use ZFS on systems which have support for it. So you won't be able to mount your SD card on a Windows box. Linux boxes also take considerable effort. Embedded devices like camera's or media players don't support ZFS at all.
- Removing and inserting the card won't be easy as well. You need to unmount the filesystem, export the zpool and do the reverse when importing (as root). Most Window Managers have support for automatic or easy mount/umount of common filesystems on removable media.

While ZFS technically might be the best choice, in practice you might be better off with FAT or NTFS.

Comment: do I have to use a zpool (which is raid but zfs from what I understood) even if I only have one sdcard?

Comment: Yes. The devices form a storage pool called a zpool from which you can create filesystems (ZFS). Volume manager and filesystem are tightly integrated. This is one of the reasons why ZFS has so many features and performance-benefits built-in.

Comment: Oh ok, is there anyway to use the sdcard on Android? (maybe with custom kernel)

Comment: Not that I know of, but why go through all the trouble. ZFS really comes into it's own with terabytes of data and multiple disks. The benefits for a single SD card are minimal, and there are some pretty big practical disadvantages. It's about using the right tool for the job, and ZFS for SD cards is not it :)

Comment: I really like the features of data deduplication CopyOnWrite block suballocation block journaling and lots more. (and I really despise fat32 bacause of so many issues like data corruption/loss I had with it)

Comment: NTFS has journalling, which should be enough to avoid most scenarios involving data corruption. Additionally, NTFS is supported on Android (with an extra app). In the end it's up to you what filesystem to use, I'm just giving my insights.

Comment: Would be kinda cool though to have an array of 4 high speed cards in a USB 3.0 or better enclosure, a micro RAID array the size of your thumb, might be a nice addition to a hypriot cluster https://blog.hypriot.com/

Comment: "Technically it doesn't really matter which filesystem you use" - this seems too wide-reaching to be true.  Technically, FAT12 wouldn't be a good choice for a device over 32MB. But more generally, many filesystems are designed to be more useful in some cases than others.

Comment: Where were you for the past 10 years since I posted this answer?